# Writing trim left in JavaScript with replace / regular expressions

Tags: javascript

I'm attempting to make a program that removes excess spaces from a string. I'm attempting to make the first two functions I expect to need. After doing some testing and consulting a classmate I can't figure out what is wrong with the second function (I'm fairly confident it's the second function)?

```
var isWhiteSpace = function(char) {
    var out = false;
    if (char === ' ' || char === '\f' || char === '\n' || char === '\r' || char === '\t') {
        out = true;
    }
    return out;
};

var removeLeadingSpaces = function(s) {
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
        if (isWhiteSpace(s.charAt(i))) {
            s.replace(s.charAt(i), '');
        }
    }
    return s;
};
```

Comment: Depending how supported this needs to be, newer browsers support an inbuilt [`trim()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim) function.

Comment: possible duplicate of [String is not defined error. JS. Is it empty space related?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13281492/string-is-not-defined-error-js-is-it-empty-space-related)

Answer (score 3):

`s = s.replace(/^\s+/,"");` would be simpler than running a loop.

This is because javascript's regular expressions already knows what whitespace is (`\s`) and knows how to pull from the beginning of a string (`^`) and can recurse on its own (`+`).

Comment: Is their a reference you would recommend for finding the definitions and uses of those terms?

Comment: @alex23 - What does IE do differently in this case?

Comment: @SashaModestyMorrison I used http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/redev2.shtml to double check what I wrote, it's a nice one-page reference.

Comment: @nnnnnn IE doesn't correctly recognize the unicode character "NO-BREAK SPACE" (\u00A0) as whitespace. If those might be in the trimmed string, you can adjust the regular expression to include that character specifically (`[\s\u00a0]`)

Comment: Thanks @alex23 and Plynx - I'd completely forgotten about that. This is one of those rare occasions where I agree with IE in principle: in my opinion a no-break space isn't really whitespace, it's (sort of) part of the words on either side. Except that of course it isn't at all helpful to have one browser marching to its own beat on these things - I'd be happy if _all_ browsers did it that way, but since they don't IE ends up being the bad guy again.

Answer (score 1):

Use `s=s.replace(s.charAt(i), '');`

The replace method doesn't modify the original string - it returns a value.

Comment: That is incorrect. Check https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace. The replace method doesn't modify the original string.

Comment: Well, obviously writing s=s.replace(...) will update s! The code in the question is 's.replace(...)', which will not modify s.